# Java: Sorting TreeSets based on size

Tags: java, sorting, set

I am looking for a way to sort a set of sets - more specifically, the data structure is required to have the following properties:

- Both the "outer" and the "inner" collection should be sets, i.e. there should be no duplicate elements within contained sets and no duplicate sets.
- The set should be sorted according to the length of the contained sets in ascending order, i.e. {{A}, {A, B}, {A, C, F}, {B, D, F}} is valid whereas {{A, C, F}, {A, B}, {B, D, F}, {A}} is not.
- It should be possible to iterate over individual contained sets as well as over all sets. Naturally, iterating over all sets should list them in ascending order based on their respective sizes.
- If two sets have the same size, the order may be arbitrary.

My basic approach is a `TreeSet<TreeSet<T>>`, although since the contained TreeSets need to be sorted in a custom behaviour, I have written a wrapper class (unnecessary details omitted, such as additional constructors and methods):

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collection;

public class WrappedSet< T > implements Comparable< WrappedSet< T >>, Iterable< T >  {
    protected TreeSet< T > set;

    public WrappedSet( Collection< T > collection ) {
        set = new TreeSet< T >( collection );
    }

    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator< T > iterator() {
        return set.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo( WrappedSet< T > other ) {
        if ( set.equals( other.set )) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return ( set.size() >= other.set.size()) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return set.toString();
    }
}
```

For the purpose of showing the problem, I am using this main function:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    TreeSet< WrappedSet< String >> wsets = new TreeSet< WrappedSet< String >>();

    for ( String arg : args ) {
        wsets.add( new WrappedSet< String >( new TreeSet< String >( Arrays.asList( arg.split( "," )))));
    }

    System.out.println( "Input sets: " + Arrays.toString( wsets.toArray()));
}
```

I understand that if my .equals() for this class was based on testing the individual sets for equality, my *"class [would have] a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals"*, as the [CompareTo documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) phrases it. I also understand that this is probably the reason why the output is (sometimes) incorrect. Consider the following example:

Input (command line): A,B,E A,C,F B,D,F A A,B,E
Output: *Input sets: [[A], [A, B, E], [A, C, F], [B, D, F], [A, B, E]]*

As you can see, {A, B, E} comes up twice, and I suppose this is because the TreeSet traverses the tree in order to find an existing entry with this value, but ends up not finding it because the order of the elements is independent of their actual values - only their sizes.

How could I achieve the desired behaviour in a consistent way? Please note that this is **not** homework. Solutions not based on TreeSets are therefore naturally welcome.

Comment: When you define a comparable, you have to make sure that for all sets, `a.compareTo(b)` never returns the same answer as `b.compareTo(a)` unless they are equal (where it has to return 0 for both). Your `compareTo` violates that rule (anti-symmetry).

Comment: You use `TreeSet.equals()` in your `compareTo()` method. This is not really working... You should implement `equals` to your class `WrappedSet`, and use this instead...

Comment: There is a possibility that your method returns 1 when two sets have equal sizes. As far as I understand, the fact that you still haven't got a "Comparison method violates its general contract!" exception is probably just a lucky coincidence.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I have implemented but omitted it. It's basically the first line of my compareTo, so I don't see how this would help, honestly.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov That's because, as I have stated, I don't care about the order when sets have equal sizes. To me it's only important whether they are equal as sets, or if they are bigger or smaller than other sets. The issue is that I don't see what I should do exactly when two sets have the same size, especially if the order doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: @Demnevanni, if you don't care about order of two particular elements, you should return `0`, not `1` or `-1`.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov You're not wrong, although in my case I suppose this would not allow sets to be added that have the same size as a set already contained. {B,C,D} and {A,C,F} are not equal, but they would not be allowed to exist within the set at the same time.

Comment: @Demnevanni, you clearly have a conflict of interest here. In order to your comparison to be consistent, you will need to, well, make it consistent, so that `a.compareTo(b) == -1 * b.compareTo(a)` at all times. That then makes your data structure of choice to discard sets that are equal (I assume that's the case). You've then two ways: (1) choose another data structure, one that won't require comparison to be consistent with equals (then it won't discard sets of equal size); or (2) Include set contents into comparison, so that comparison is consistent with equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your outer `TreeSet` to accept two different sets of the same size as different elements, you need to decide a sorting order of them even when you don’t care about their order. Otherwise your set will not work as you expected.

Rather then a wrapper class for the inner `TreeSet`s I think I’d prefer just to write a comparator. But make sure your comparator defines a total ordering on the inner sets and only declares two sets equal of they are indeed equal also in the sense that only one of them should be in the set. And as RealSkeptic and others have said in comments, in order to fulfil the `Comparator` contract, you need to fulfil:

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) ==
>   -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`.

(from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-))

Here’s just a very rough example of a `Comparator` that does compare more than just the size when the size is the same. It’s not hard to devise an example where it still doesn’t do well enough, but I will leave it to you to write the right comparator for your situation.

```
    Comparator<TreeSet<?>> compareBySize 
            = Comparator.comparing((TreeSet<?> s) -> s.size())
                    .thenComparing(TreeSet::toString);

    TreeSet<TreeSet<Character>> mySet = new TreeSet<>(compareBySize);
    mySet.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'E')),
                new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'C', 'F')),
                new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList('B', 'D', 'F')),
                new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList('A')),
                new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'E'))
            ));
    System.out.println(mySet);
```

This prints

```
[[A], [A, B, E], [A, C, F], [B, D, F]]
```

I believe this is correct.

As an aside, it is generally recommended to program towards interfaces rather than implementations. If you want to do this, depending on your further requirements, either use the `SortedSet` or the `NavigableSet` interface. You need two changes: First, the comparator should be (using `SortedSet` in my example):

```
    Comparator<SortedSet<?>> compareBySize 
            = Comparator.comparing((SortedSet<?> s) -> s.size())
                    .thenComparing(SortedSet::toString);
```

Second declare your set as `SortedSet<SortedSet<Character>> mySet`, but still use `new TreeSet<>(…)` in the instantiations.